# Get all file from Fileentry laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with laravel and want to fetch all file stored in Fileentry with all info. What is the way ?

I am trying with

```
$files = Storage::files($directory);

// Recursive...
$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);
```

But getting empty result.

Comment: My guess is that you have a configuration issue. Check out config/filesystems.php and make sure that the info is correct for your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found this , you can fetch all files from Fileentry as below

```
$fileentry = new Fileentry();
$allFiles= $fileentry->get()->toArray();
print_r($allFiles);
```